# seaborn barplot to compare values from a dataframe with two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, visualization

I have a dataFrame that looks kind of like this.

```
      - X_1     - X_2     - X3      - ....
0     - float64 - float64 - float64 - ...
1     - ...
```

Example: `df=pd.DataFrame({"X_1": [4, 2], "X_2": [2, 3], "X_3": [1, 1]})`

In my case, there are two rows and a few dozen columns.
I'm trying to make a barplot that shows the values at index 0 and 1 side-by-side, from greatest to smallest, sorted on Index 0. e.g.,

```
      |
      |  0
value |  0         1
      |  0 1     0 1
      |  0 1     0 1     0 1
      _______________________
         X_1     X_2     X_3
```

When I try to run the command below, I get a couple different errors.

I run this:
`order=df.sort_values(df.iloc[0], ascending=False).df.columns`

And get this:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values`

If i just ignor ordering, I try this:
`sns.barplot(df, x=df.columns, y=df.values)`

I get this: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I'm suspecting that I need to re-shape my dataFrame so it is friendier.
I think the shape that might work is somethinging like below.

```
Category - Y_1     - Y2
X_1      - float64 - float64
X_2      - float64 - float64
X_3      - float64 - float64
...
```

Then, I think I could successfully do my ordering and plotting like blow.

Order. `order=df.sort_values(Y_1, ascending=False).Category Plot.` sns.barplot(df, x=df.Category, y=df.columns~'Category')

My question is:
How do I get the desired plot (illustrated above) from my dataframe?
I outlined something that I think my lead there but this could be completely ill guided.
Please let me know if you have any ideas.
Thnank you!

Comment: `sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index'), x='variable', y='value', hue='index')` to use seaborn, reset the index to use as a column for `hue` and convert to a long form with `.melt`. [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExW1F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

This will give you (using the `df` defined in your question):

[image]

Comment: If this is not what you want, please let me know :)

Comment: Yes! this is almost exactly what I needed! However, is there a way to order it greatest-to-least if X_1, X_2. X_3 aren't already sorted? I should have used an example where they weren't already.